# Redirect ASMX to another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, asmx

I've hit a blocker with an issue I'm working on, any suggestions gratefully received.  I am using a web service which has moved to a new server.

The URL has shifted from

https://www.example.co.uk/webservice/api.asmx

to

http://www.example.co.uk/webapistd/api.asmx

If I update the web reference in the .net project and run the code, I receive a 301 Moved Permanently error (no redirect URL is sent through).

Note this is an old style web reference, not a service reference.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be behind this? I'm pretty sure the new URL is correct.

Could it be something else that gets masked as a 301 error, e.g. a different SOAP version?

Just trying to cast the net further rather than rewriting to use a service reference (which may or may not resolve the issue).

Comment: If only the address of web service has changed, you can simply set the new  Url when calling the service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I set the URL in code?

Comment: Yes you can. For example  `var svc = new Service1(); svc.Url = "http://www.example.co.uk/webapistd/api.asmx";`

Comment: Also if you check Settings of your project, you will see an entry in the `Settings.settings` that contains the address of web service. You can update the value of that setting.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Check below mentioned files of your project to check if the reference to the new web service has updated correctly
(Example : “https” to “http”)

1. Web.config
2. Reference.map
3. YourwebserviceName.disco (api.disco)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

When calling an `asmx WebService` that you have added its reference to your project, visual studio creates an entry in `Settings.settings` ans sets its value to the url that you added service.

When you call `var svc= new Service1();` it uses the value of that setting as Url of service.

To change the url:

- you can change the default url in the `Settings.settings`
- You can pass the new url to service simply using `svc.Url="your new url";`

Comment: Thanks for you comments.